# Hide submit button after submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery

After submit, I want the submit button to get hide via jQuery. It hides, but soon after the page reloads... Why?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="js/submit_rsvp.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.2.3.pack.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form name="rsvp" method="post" action="" id='form'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' id='submit' class='clickMe'>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".clickMe").click(function() {
$("submit").hide();
});
});
```

Thanks! 
Coulton

Comment: As opposed to.. _what_ desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form action is empty. So when you click submit it'll just use the current page as the action. That's why it reloads the current page. If you don't want it to submit the form you can do:

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("submit").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you submit, the page reloads and every thing is square one again. Try following.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".clickMe").click(function() {
$("submit").hide();
return false;
});
});
```

Comment: It seems fairly likely that the OP wants to hide the submit button during submission, not instead of it.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because it is a `submit` button, which causes the form to produce a new POST query and the page to reload. Add:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

at the beginning of your anonymous function to override this default behavior.